# Как прикрутить к Label ползунок?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

Если в Label не вмещается текст, то как прикрутить ползунок?

Comment: А другие решения изначальной проблемы (кстати, какая она?) не устроят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно к TLabel - только путем страшных извращений.

К TStaticText уже проще - при перемещении ползунка вызывать ScrollBy(…)

А если хочется автоматически - положите TMemo без обводки, с ReadOnly = True;

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, всё-таки можно, но сколько придётся  переписать кода - жуть! :) Проблема в том, что TLabel не наследуется от TWinControl и, как следствие, не получает фокус. Поэтому просто так скроллбар к нему не прикрутить.

Но "если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно" :) Просто немного по-другому: положите на форму ListBox, задайте ему свойства

```
ParentColor := true;
BorderStyle:=bsNone;
```

В свойстве Items задайте первую строку (если необходимо, сделайте в рантайме). Это будет ваш Caption от Label. 
Высоту задайте так, чтобы она вмещала текст первой строки и скроллбар. Затем, когда необходимо (или сразу во время создания формы) вызовите:

```
SendMessage(listbox1.handle,LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT,1000,0);
```

Вы получили то, что хотели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну почему же нельзя прикрутить скролл бар? Очень даже можно. Только как отдельный компонент - `TScrollBar`. Нужно будет вызвать [SetSubComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TComponent.SetSubComponent) в конструкторе компонента `TLabel` и делов). Правда, придется создавать новый компонент, конечно...